# How do I enable hardware virtualization in BIOS from Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, bios, virtualization, lenovo-laptop

I'm trying to enable hardware virtualization in the BIOS of my i5 [Lenovo G570 laptop](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-g-series-laptops/lenovo-g570-notebook) from Windows. Because of my laptop BIOS is password-protected and I forgot it, I could not directly access the BIOS.

Is there any way to enable hardware virtualization in BIOS from Windows 10 OS?

Comment: No, it's not possible.  There are ways to remove the password from the BIOS, but you'll need to do some research on google.  I would first recommend contacting Lenovo tech support, as this is a fairly common issue.

Comment: @JW0914 Thanks for your comment, I called to lenovo tech support they told me full in structure to remove the BIOS password, But it take time and I'm in hurry.

Comment: There is no way to access the BIOS from an OS, so you'll first need to perform the steps required to remove the password.

Comment: @spikey_richie My laptop partition schema is MBR not working with UEFI apps.

Comment: @spikey_richie BIOS [**B**asic **I**nput / **O**utput **S**ystem] and UEFI [**U**nified **E**xtensible **F**irmware **I**nterface] are not the same things... there is no way that I'm aware of to access the BIOS from an OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows does not have access to the BIOS settings.  There are a few motherboards out there that do have software that allows access to some BIOS settings, but are rare.

You will have to unlock the BIOS.  Check your motherboard/computer manual on how to do a reset.

Comment: @Gabriel He's absolutely right. A web link to Lenovo's manuals and support section has been added to your question.